# Как составить SQL-запрос с взаимоисключающими условиями

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно составить запрос с взаимоисключающими условиями.

Пример запроса:

```
 $country = 'it';
    $country_group = 'europe';

    SELECT s.id, s.name
    FROM subject s
    WHERE s.field1 = '{$field1}'
        AND s.field2 = '{$field2}'
        AND (
            EXISTS (select * from subject_country sc where s.id = sc.subject_id and sc.country = '{$country}')
            OR (
                NOT EXISTS (select * from subject_country sc where s.id = sc.subject_id and sc.country = '{$country}') 
                AND s.country_group = '{$country_group}'
                )
            )
```

нужно достать один subject: 
1) если есть subject с указанными условиями + country, значит не проверяем country_group 
2) если нет subject условия + country, то достаем по country_group.

Comment: Либо OR во WHERE, либо UNION.

Comment: OR который стоит у меня в примере не подходит, т.к. мне нужно сначала проверить нет ли subject c country во всех subject c filed1&field2, и только если нет таких вообще, проверить этот же запрос с условием указанным после OR.
Не понимаю, как мне здесь поможет UNION?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, структуры таблиц в виде `create table` выражений. Почему я должен тратить свое время, восстанавливая их по запросам?!

Comment: `create table subjects (
    id integer not null primary key,  
    name varchar(10),
    country_group varchar(25),
    field1 integer,
    field2 integer )`
  
  `create table subject_country ( 
    subject_id integer foreign key references subjects (id), 
    country varchar(2) )`

Comment: Запрос должен вернуть именно один `subject` или может быть несколько, которые удовлетворят условиям или-или?

Comment: subject только один нужно найти. Если есть хоть один subject с нужной country берем его, и не важно какой у него country_group. Если такого нет, то country_group обязательно должен учитываться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так - пример ниже и на [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5n26Ks7kC3kXSto6ig4MBe/2)

```
SELECT s.id, s.name
FROM subject s
JOIN subject_country sc
ON s.id = sc.subject_id and sc.country = 'fr'
WHERE s.field1 = 1 and s.field2 = 2
UNION
SELECT id, name
FROM subject
WHERE country_group = 'europe' AND
      field1 = 1 and field2 = 2
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает! Правда field1 и field2 - это для примера, реально у меня большой запрос, не хотелось писать его дважды с небольшими изменениями.

Comment: Так вроде бы тоже работает:

`
SELECT q.id, q.name, q.country, q.country_group
    FROM (
     SELECT s.id, s.name, (CASE WHEN sc.country IS NULL THEN s.country_group ELSE NULL END) country_group, (CASE WHEN sc.country IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) country
     FROM subjects s
        LEFT JOIN subject_country sc ON (s.id = sc.subject_id and sc.country = 'it')
     WHERE s.field1 = 1
         AND s.field2 = 2
    ) q
    WHERE q.country IS NOT NULL
     OR q.country_group = 'europe'
        limit 1
`

Comment: Да, работает. Но когда я задаю страну `fr`, совершенно неочевидно, почему `gr` всплывает вверх выдачи. Видимо, из-за финального `WHERE`, где сначала выбираются записи с совпавшей страной, а затем с группой. Добавьте `ORDER BY q.country DESC` для надежности. Также не уверен насколько `CASE` элементы будут влиять на скорость выборки...

Comment: *Видимо, из-за финального WHERE* Нет. Из-за отсутствия сортировки финального (объединённого) набора. И вообще, LIMIT без ORDER BY - это БСК и лотерея.

Comment: @Akina, а БСК это что? :)

Comment: Это - аббревиатура, означает "нелогичные высказывания самки лошади серовато-сизой масти".